# How to find out DHCP info on Android for a non-WiFi connection?

Tags: android, dhcp

I have Android device, which is connected to a network through Ethernet. How can I get DHCP info for this connection?

Answer (score 1):

There is no WifiManager like class for non-Wifi.

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Service.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);


                        Log.i("routes ", connectivityManager.getLinkProperties(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork()).getRoutes().toString());
                        Log.i("domains ", connectivityManager.getLinkProperties(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork()).getDomains().toString());
                        Log.i("ip address ", connectivityManager.getLinkProperties(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork()).getLinkAddresses().toString());
                        Log.i("dns address ", connectivityManager.getLinkProperties(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork()).getDnsServers().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `ConnectivityManager.getAllNetworks()` to get the connected network array:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getAllNetworks()

And then `Network.getSocketFactory()` for your connected network. The `SocketFactory` will allow you to inspect `Socket`s that can be created on the connection.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Network.html#getSocketFactory()

From that, simply create a `Socket` from the `SocketFactory.createSocket()` and it will have the info you want, like `Socket.getLocalSocketAddress()` etc.

http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/SocketFactory.html#createSocket()

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html